# Matching file name using regex in C++

Tags: c++, regex

I want to match a file name using regex in C++. The form of the desired file name is 
"ProjectXX.txt" where X should be a digit. The code with the regex I use looks:

```
static const wregex initFile(L"(\\Project)(\\d\\d)\\.(\\txt)");
wsmatch result;
if(regex_match(fileName, result, initFile))
```

I need `CString` (therefore `L""`) since I use windows.h. However the code throws an exception and although I tried to modify the regex, I could not manage it to match the file name. What is the correct regular expression?

Comment: `L"Project[0-9]{2}.txt"` ... I think.

Answer (score 0):

@hmjd's comment is almost right, but a bit too wide. It will also accept `L"Project[0-9]{2}@txt"`. You want `L"Project[0-9]{2}\\.txt"`

Comment: And how is `"[0-9]{2}"` different from `"\\d\\d"`?  (Presumably, too, he needs the capture created by the parentheses.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Personal preference, I avoid `\ ` in C++ regex'es when it's reasonable.  It can quickly become unreadable.

Comment: I can understand that.  (Of course, if you have `regex` in standard C++, you also have raw strings:-).  But with boost::regex...)  But in this case, he'd already used `\\d`, and his regular expression was correct in that regard.  I'd have at least mentioned the reason why his regular expression was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

What's the purpose of the `\\` in front of `P` and  `t`?  The first will
probably cause an error, since regular expressions don't have an escape
sequence `\P`.  Drop those (`L"(Project)(\d\d)\.(txt)"), and it
should work.

And while I'm at it: why the capture of strings that must be constants.
I'd write this `L"Project(\\d\\d)\\.text"`, and be done with it, just
using `L"Project"` and `L"txt"` rather than the first and third
captures.